# useMemo function cannot run in useCallback

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

i follow this [link](https://kyleshevlin.com/debounce-and-throttle-callbacks-with-react-hooks) to handle input:

```
  const handleSearch = useMemo(() => {
    _.debounce(text => {
      console.log(text);
    });
  }, []);

  const handleOnSearch = useCallback(
    text => {
      handleSearch(text);
    },
    [handleSearch],
  );
```

but i get error: `handleSearch is not a function` (this error only trigger when i enter text into the input)

But if i use this code, everything ok:

```
  const handleSearch = useRef(
    _.debounce(over => {
      console.log(over);
    }, 1000),
  );

  const handleOnSearch = useCallback(text => {
    setTextSearch(text);
    handleSearch.current(text);
  }, []);
```

Can someone explain to me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the value from `_.debounce` so `handleSearch` gets undefined

```
  const handleSearch = useMemo(() => {
    return _.debounce(text => {    // use return here
      console.log(text);
    });
  }, []);
```

`useMemo` returns the value from the callback, passed to it as argument. And your callback does not return anything.

You can do it like this as well, the same as using `useRef`:

```
   const handleSearch = useCallback(
    _.debounce(text => {
      console.log(text);
  }), []);
```

But here `_.debounce` will execute on each render

Comment: you can use useMemo instead of useCallback so _.debounce will be only called once

Answer (score 0):

useMemo is expecting a callback and it will return the callback result.
its purpose is to cache the result so the callback doesn't need to be re-run every time the component is rendered.

So since the callback sent to useMemo doesn't return a value, `handleSearch` is undefined. this is how you fix it:

```
const handleSearch = useMemo(() => {
    return _.debounce(text => {
        console.log(text);
    });
}, []);

const handleOnSearch = useCallback(
   text => {
       handleSearch(text);
   }, [handleSearch]);
```

however - I don't see much purpose is the way you are combining useMemo and useCallback, since the handleSearch never changes, and handOnSearch only calls handleSearch.
Therefore, you can reduce them to a single useMemo (you can use useCallback but I think this is slightly more readable):

```
const handleSearch = useMemo(() => {
    return _.debounce(text => console.log(text));  
}, []);
```

and then whenever you use `handleOnSearch` just use `handleSearch`